# Defining os_path in ansible jinja template

Tags: python, ansible

I need to include an if statement in my httpd.conf template based on whether a directory exists.
Here is what i have so far

```
{% if ansible_distribution_major_version > 7 and os.path.exists ("/opt/myapp/testapp") %}Include conf/vhost.conf{% endif %}
```

I get an os is undefined error when i run the task. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't write arbitrary Python code inside Jinja2 expression.

Run Ansible `stat` module and register result before templating and use this result instead of `os.path.exists`.

Comment: Thank you. Don't know why i never thought of that. :)